# php use html same content but does not work

Tags: php, html

I want to use php in html at first, but I found the way is creates .htaccess file and does not work, so I use php to code the same html then do task in php.
The reason why I want to use php in html is that I want to store data in database per 10 seconds.
But my html use css to design the layout, and when I use same code in php, the .php file can not works as html in IE browser. However, I use firefox and crome browser, it works fine. I recently use IE6, and I am not sure it is related to IE browser or not...
My code in html originally is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcom to My CAM</title>
<style>
#extend{
display: none; //預設為隱藏
}
#close{
display: block; //預設為顯示
}
#extend2{
display: none; //預設為隱藏
}
#close2{
display: block; //預設為顯示
}
#extend3{
display: none; //預設為隱藏
}
#close3{
display: block; //預設為顯示
}
body {
    background-color: #CC6633;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
//第一個參數為欲顯示的區塊，第二個參數為欲隱藏的區塊
function exchange(show,hidden){
if(document.getElementById(show).style.display = 'none'){
document.getElementById(show).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';
}
}
function change1_1(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1c.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change1_2(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2c.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change1_3(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3c.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change2_1(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1c.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change2_2(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2c.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change2_3(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3c.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change3_1(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1c.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change3_2(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2c.png";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1">
<div id="close">
<img src="images/btn1.png" onClick="exchange('extend','close')">
<!-- 顯示 extend 同時隱藏 close -->
</div>
<div id="extend">
<img src="images/btn1.png" onClick="exchange('close','extend')">
<a href="index4.html" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn1_1.png" id="img1_1" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change1_1()"/></a>
<a href="mac.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn1_2.png" id="img1_2" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change1_2()" /></a>
<a href="ipcam.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn1_3.png" id="img1_3" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change1_3()" /></a>
<!-- 顯示 close 同時隱藏 extend -->
</div>
<div id="close2">
<img src="images/btn2.png" onClick="exchange('extend2','close2')">
<!-- 顯示 extend 同時隱藏 close -->
</div>
<div id="extend2">
<img src="images/btn2.png" onClick="exchange('close2','extend2')">
<a href="account.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn2_1.png" id="img2_1" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change2_1()" /></a>
<a href="actives.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn2_2.png" id="img2_2" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change2_2()" /></a>
<a href="index4.html" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn2_3.png" id="img2_3" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change2_3()" /></a>
<!-- 顯示 close 同時隱藏 extend -->
</div>
<div id="close3">
<img src="images/btn3.png" onClick="exchange('extend3','close3')">
<!-- 顯示 extend 同時隱藏 close -->
</div>
<div id="extend3">
<img src="images/btn3.png" onClick="exchange('close3','extend3')">
<a href="index4.html" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn3_1.png" id="img3_1" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change3_1()" /></a>
<a href="index4.html" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn3_2.png" id="img3_2" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change3_2()" /></a>
<!-- 顯示 close 同時隱藏 extend -->
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Just to use css to do menu that can be hide/visible, it runs in IE is successfully.
And to combine with php, my php code is:

```
   <?php 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  include "./databases.php";
  //echo $_POST["selectmenu"]."test";
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  $result = mysql_query('select * from user ;');        //;needed!
   if(!$result){
        echo 'Execute SQL failed : ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
   }
   ?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style>
#extend{
display: none; //預設為隱藏
}
#close{
display: block; //預設為顯示
}
#extend2{
display: none; //預設為隱藏
}
#close2{
display: block; //預設為顯示
}
#extend3{
display: none; //預設為隱藏
}
#close3{
display: block; //預設為顯示
}
body {
    background-color: #CC6633;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
//第一個參數為欲顯示的區塊，第二個參數為欲隱藏的區塊
function exchange(show,hidden){
if(document.getElementById(show).style.display = 'none'){
document.getElementById(show).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';
}
}
function change1_1(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1c.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change1_2(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2c.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change1_3(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3c.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change2_1(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1c.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change2_2(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2c.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change2_3(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3c.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change3_1(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1c.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2.png";
}
function change3_2(){
    document.getElementById("img1_1").src="images/btn1_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_2").src="images/btn1_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img1_3").src="images/btn1_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_1").src="images/btn2_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_2").src="images/btn2_2.png";
    document.getElementById("img2_3").src="images/btn2_3.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_1").src="images/btn3_1.png";
    document.getElementById("img3_2").src="images/btn3_2c.png";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>  
<form id="form1">
<div id="close">
<img src="images/btn1.png" onClick="exchange('extend','close')">
<!-- 顯示 extend 同時隱藏 close -->
</div>
<div id="extend">
<img src="images/btn1.png" onClick="exchange('close','extend')">
<a href="index4.html" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn1_1.png" id="img1_1" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change1_1()"/></a>
<a href="mac.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn1_2.png" id="img1_2" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change1_2()" /></a>
<a href="ipcam.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn1_3.png" id="img1_3" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change1_3()" /></a>
<!-- 顯示 close 同時隱藏 extend -->
</div>
<div id="close2">
<img src="images/btn2.png" onClick="exchange('extend2','close2')">
<!-- 顯示 extend 同時隱藏 close -->
</div>
<div id="extend2">
<img src="images/btn2.png" onClick="exchange('close2','extend2')">
<a href="account.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn2_1.png" id="img2_1" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change2_1()" /></a>
<a href="actives.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn2_2.png" id="img2_2" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change2_2()" /></a>
<a href="index4.html" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn2_3.png" id="img2_3" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change2_3()" /></a>
<!-- 顯示 close 同時隱藏 extend -->
</div>
<div id="close3">
<img src="images/btn3.png" onClick="exchange('extend3','close3')">
<!-- 顯示 extend 同時隱藏 close -->
</div>
<div id="extend3">
<img src="images/btn3.png" onClick="exchange('close3','extend3')">
<a href="index4.html" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn3_1.png" id="img3_1" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change3_1()" /></a>
<a href="index4.html" target="mainFrame"><img src="images/btn3_2.png" id="img3_2" align="right" Style="border:0px solid " onClick="change3_2()" /></a>
<!-- 顯示 close 同時隱藏 extend -->
</div>
</form>
<?
        header("Refresh:10");
            $handle=fopen("userfile.txt","w+");
            $content="";
            if($handle)
            {
                while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                    $userId = $rows[userId];
                    $userMail = $rows[userMail];

                    $content.=$userId.";".$userMail.";";    

                }

                $num=fwrite($handle, $content);
                fclose($handle);
                #echo $num;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "There is something wrong.";
            }
?>
</body>         
</html>
```

It connects to database in the beginning, and in `<body>` part, it do the php code to store data.

It can store data well, but the UI in IE can not work.

What's wrong with it?

Any help appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Yeah! I can not believe it! It worked!
But why? I seem that two line do not need to add in php before...
Can you teach me the different about the two line from I do not add? (because even I do not add, it can work in firefox or crome)

Comment: [You can read more about doctype here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) but basically it tells the browser to use certain version of html to parse your code. If you dont have it, the browsers will use its' own default one and your website will not be consistent across browsers. Dont forget the upvote :D

Answer (score 1):

CSS comments are in the form...

```
/* this is a comment in CSS */
```

I suspect that the `//` is at least part of your problem where IE is concerned.